# check if function is async in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.7

I'd like to check if  a function is async before calling it in python. For example, here I'd like to check if `f` is async so that await makes sense:

```
async def call_async_f(f):
    assert function_is_async(f)
    await f()
```

How could I implement `function_is_async`? I'm using python 3.7 which seems to have some interesting new async features and I don't mind a 3.7-specific solution.

Comment: Why not try-except?

Comment: A function doesn't have to be defined as `async` for the return value to be awaitable.

Comment: That's a bad idea because the `f` could be a sync function that returns an awaitable (a `Future`, a coroutine objects, etc.), just like an iterable can be of many different types...

Answer (score 3):

[inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) has checks for most types of async objects, in your case it`s [iscoroutinefunction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.iscoroutinefunction)

```
import inspect
async def call_async_f(f):
    assert inspect.iscoroutinefunction(f)
    await f()
```